# What does an LSTM do when it gets 2 or more numeric features?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Based on the spec that an LSTM works by receiving this input
(samples, time-steps, features)

What does it do by default (no custom code) when it gets , let's say,   2 numeric features?
Does it considers the two numbers as combination of the sequence?
Tries to arithmetically combining them?

Answer (score 1):

We can start by understanding the dimensions of the LSTM input -

**sample** - one training example for a LSTM is a sequence - number of samples is essentially number of sequences 
**time-steps** - each sequence is represented by a fixed number of time steps(padding is done accordingly if needed) 
**features** - each time step is represented by a vector of fixed size

In general, RNNs, are multiple copies of the same neural networks each passing a message to the successor.

Each copy(vanilla NN) receives the i<sup>th</sup> time step in the sequence which can be represented by n features.

So for any number of features representing a time step the functionality remains the same - where each Vanilla NN might output a single/multiple/no value(depending on design of NN).
And, in addition to generating the output which is a function of the input and hidden state, we update the hidden state itself based on the input and use it in processing the next input(next time step).